# Is there any API to connect to MySpace using Blackberry app

Tags: api, blackberry, myspace

I'm building Blackberry application, and I need to post message to MySpace using oAuth.
I keep searching for API but could not find any.
Could anybody help me on this please.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wiki.developer.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category:RESTful_API

I would consume the JSON response in your app as JSON is a part of OS 6.0.0+ and you can roll the JSON source into other versions such as 5.0.0-.